# Can we stop Task Router from creating reservation of a Task in queue having available workers?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-taskrouter

**Objective:** Manually route tasks (calls) in some specific queue `WQ_i` within some timeout

**How:** Update a task in Task Router by setting worker sid to `known_worker_sid`

After going through the documentation of Twilio Task Router, I came to know that:

1. A task can be updated after the creation
2. If we set `known_worker_sid` in a task, Task Router will route to that specific worker

So, to achieve the *objective*, I want to use *task update*, *Known Worker Routing* and customize the *Workflow* definition. Let's have the following workflow:

```json
{  
  "task_routing":{
    "filters":[  
      { 
        "expression": "type == 'WQ_i'",
        "targets":[  
          {  
            "queue": "SID_of_WQ_i",
            "timeout": "300",
            "expression": "0==1" ===> Some always false expression
          },
          {  
            "queue": "SID_of_WQ_i",
            "timeout": "60"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "default_filter":{  
      "queue": "<default task queue sid>"
    }
  }
}
```

As per my understanding, this workflow will allow me to manually route (by updating the task and setting `known_worker_sid`) every task in queue `WQ_i` within 300 seconds. However, if I cannot update the task within 300 seconds, it will fall to the next target having the same queue but Task Router can create reservation for any available worker.

**Questions:**

1. What does the Task Router do with the task if a worker with sid set to `known_worker_sid` is unavailable (busy or not logged-in)?
2. Will the `"expression": "0==1"` (or some other expression which always evaluates to false) stop Task Router from creating reservations on that target till timeout?

Answer (score 1):

Review the [Lifecycle of a Task](https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/lifecycle-task-state) document. If a known_worker_sid is unavailable, it will go to the next available worker. This is described in the [known agent routing](https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/workflow-configuration/known-agent-routing) document.

If you do not have workers available, you can have Taskrouter keep them on hold or send the caller to a voicemail and use the voicemail process to create a task. This [Queued Callback and Voicemail](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/solutions-library/queued-callback-and-voicemail) document outlines the process which will work with or without Flex.